# CurrentDB.Execute locks the database for exclusive use

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2003

I have one function in my Access database which is putting the database in exclusive lock situation.

```
    Sub PrepareYears(Aar As Integer)

    CurrentDB.Execute "DELETE FROM HKE_Years"

    CurrentDB.Execute "INSERT INTO HKE_Years ( Years ) VALUES (" & Aar & ")"

    CurrentDB.Execute "INSERT INTO HKE_Years ( Years ) VALUES (" & Aar - 1 & ")"
End Sub
```

I have set the database options to "Shared" and "No Lock" from advanced options too.

Please guide, this has been troubling me since 48 hours now.

Thanks,
Hardik

Comment: The first command will lock the table while running but not the database. So something else is going on.

Comment: If you have multiple users, I would recommend splitting your DB into a separate front end and back end.  This will mitigate a majority of the conflicts you're experiencing.